# DropDownList Selected Value not returned on postback in Update Panel (Sharepoint 2010 WebPart)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am working on a SharePoint 2010 webpart that I setup this way: in an asp:UpdatePanel, there is a drop down list and a chart control. When the page loads for the first time, the list is populated with options, and the chart is bound with a general data set based on the drop down's "all" value. When the user selects a value from the dropdown, a SQL query is created with the user's selection, the database is queried and the chart is loaded with new data based the user's selection.

Fairly straightforward, except that when my user selects a value from the dropdown, the SelectedValue property is not being retured to my code; it always shows empty in debugging. And yet, the default dropdown value is returned when the page loads the first time.

Here is my code as it is now. On the front end [edited]:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList><p />

        <WebChartControl>
            // code code code
        </WebChartControl>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dropDownList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

And in the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
         // Do setup stuff, get dropdown's default selected value
    }

    Param = dropDownList.SelectedValue; // returns empty ("") when page is PostBack    
}
```

I'm trying to get the variable on Page Load every time because I noticed it wasn't being populated elsewhere; I thought that might solve the problem, but obviously not. Also, I tried switching the trigger event to a button click (ie, user selects a value from the drop down list, then clicks a button to make things happen,) but no change.

Take away the update panel, and everything runs fine. Drop down list selected values get returned like bad presents :)

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: your trigger has different id and your dropdown has different id

Comment: it's according to asp page life cycle. every refresh to the page, it will reconstruct its variable and recreate them with new values which is different from the first time loaded. I think you have to avoid the Page load handler from doing that by this condition **if(!Page_ispostback)**, and try to get selected value of the dropdownlist inside the condition

Comment: @Ehsan thanks for catching that. That's not the case in my for real code, so I've edited the example I give here

Comment: @Ehsan but the page is postback; I'm trying to get the drop down's selected value on the postback! And if I put this variable elsewhere, such as in a separate method, it still returns empty. This variable does not return empty when the code isn't running inside an update panel, so ... there's my problem. What's the solution?

Comment: @bmurrel30, are you able to retrieve the variable in the event handler of the SlectedIndexChanged event of the control? Events occur AFTER Page.OnLoad. You could try Page.OnPreRender instead. The value should be available there.